# Set order for three crossing arrows

Tags: tikz-arrows, tikz-cd, commutative-diagrams

I am drawing a diagram with 27 points in three dimensions, three layers of nine points. What I would like to do is be able to prioritize how lines cross over each other. When I use "crossing over", one line seems to automatically cross over any other line it touches.
For example, the line between 14 and 15 should overlap the line between 11 and 20 because it is more in the front, but the line between 9 and 18 should overlap the one between 14 and 15 because it is in the front. If I use "crossing over" for the 14->15, it overlaps 9->18, even if I use "crossing over" there, also. Here is the code I'm using:

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\usepackage{tikz-cd}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzcd}[cells={nodes={draw=gray}}, row sep=scriptsize, column sep=scriptsize]
& & & & 1 \arrow[dll, dash] \arrow[rrr, dash] \arrow[ddd, dash] & & & 2 \arrow[dll, dash] \arrow[rrr, dash] \arrow[ddd, dash] & & & 3 \arrow[dll, dash] \arrow[ddd, dash] \\
& & 4 \arrow[dll, dash] \arrow[rrr, crossing over, dash] \arrow[ddd, dash] & & & 5 \arrow[dll, crossing over, dash] \arrow[rrr, crossing over, dash] \arrow[ddd, dash] & & & 6 \arrow[dll, crossing over, dash] \arrow[ddd, dash] & &\\
 7 \arrow[rrr, crossing over, dash] \arrow[ddd, dash] & & & 8 \arrow[rrr, crossing over, dash] \arrow[ddd, dash] & & & 9 \arrow[ddd, crossing over, dash] & & & &\\
 & & & & 10 \arrow[dll, dash] \arrow[rrr, dash] \arrow[ddd, dash] & & & 11 \arrow[dll, dash] \arrow[rrr, dash] \arrow[ddd, dash] & & & 12 \arrow[dll, dash] \arrow[ddd, dash] \\
& & 13 \arrow[dll, dash] \arrow[rrr, crossing over, dash] \arrow[ddd, dash] & & & 14 \arrow[dll, dash] \arrow[rrr, crossing over, dash] \arrow[ddd, dash] & & & 15 \arrow[dll, dash] \arrow[ddd, dash] & &\\
 16 \arrow[rrr, crossing over, dash] \arrow[ddd, dash] & & & 17 \arrow[rrr, crossing over, dash] \arrow[ddd, dash] & & & 18 \arrow[ddd, dash] & & & &\\
& & & & 19 \arrow[dll, dash] \arrow[rrr, dash] & & & 20 \arrow[dll, dash] \arrow[rrr, dash] & & & 21 \arrow[dll, dash] \\
& & 22 \arrow[dll, dash] \arrow[rrr, crossing over, dash] & & & 23 \arrow[dll, dash] \arrow[rrr, crossing over, dash] & & & 24 \arrow[dll, dash] & &\\
25 \arrow[rrr, crossing over, dash] & & & 26 \arrow[rrr, crossing over, dash] & & & 27 & & & &\\
\end{tikzcd}
\end{document}
```

Thank you for your help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can defer the arrow using `from` key. For example from `9` don't draw the arrow to `18` but from `18` draw it like

```
18  \arrow[from=uuu, crossing over]
```

so that it appears to be on top.

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\usepackage{tikz-cd}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzcd}[cells={nodes={draw=gray}}, row sep=scriptsize, column sep=scriptsize]
& & & & 1 \arrow[dll, dash] \arrow[rrr, dash] \arrow[ddd, dash] & & & 2 \arrow[dll, dash] \arrow[rrr, dash] \arrow[ddd, dash] & & & 3 \arrow[dll, dash] \arrow[ddd, dash] \\
& & 4 \arrow[dll, dash] \arrow[rrr, crossing over, dash] \arrow[ddd, dash] & & & 5 \arrow[dll, crossing over, dash] \arrow[rrr, crossing over, dash] \arrow[ddd, dash] & & & 6 \arrow[dll, crossing over, dash] & &\\
 7 \arrow[rrr, crossing over, dash] \arrow[ddd, dash] & & & 8 \arrow[rrr, crossing over, dash] & & & 9 & & & &\\
 & & & & 10 \arrow[dll, dash] \arrow[rrr, dash] \arrow[ddd, dash] & & & 11 \arrow[dll, dash] \arrow[rrr, dash] \arrow[ddd, dash] & & & 12 \arrow[dll, dash] \arrow[ddd, dash] \\
& & 13 \arrow[dll, dash] \arrow[rrr, crossing over, dash] \arrow[ddd, dash] & & & 14 \arrow[ddd,crossing over,dash]\arrow[rrr, crossing over, dash] \arrow[ddd, dash] & & & 15 \arrow[from=uuu,crossing over, dash]& &\\
 16 \arrow[rrr, crossing over, dash] \arrow[ddd, dash] & & & 17 \arrow[from=rru,crossing over, dash] \arrow[from=uuu,crossing over, dash]\arrow[rrr, crossing over, dash] & & & 18 \arrow[from=rru,crossing over, dash] \arrow[from=uuu, crossing over,dash] & & & &\\
& & & & 19 \arrow[dll, dash] \arrow[rrr, dash] & & & 20 \arrow[dll, dash] \arrow[rrr, dash] & & & 21 \arrow[dll, dash] \\
& & 22 \arrow[dll, dash] \arrow[rrr, crossing over, dash] & & & 23 \arrow[dll, dash] \arrow[rrr, crossing over, dash] & & & 24 \arrow[from=uuu,crossing over, dash] \arrow[dll, dash] & &\\
25 \arrow[rrr, crossing over, dash] & & & 26 \arrow[from=uuu,crossing over, dash]\arrow[rrr, crossing over, dash] & & & 27 \arrow[from=uuu,crossing over, dash]& & & &\\
\end{tikzcd}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: This works almost everywhere. The lines I'm still having trouble getting correct are the 5 -> 14 and 14 -> 23 lines. They are under correctly, but should cross over 10 ->11 and 19 -> 20, respectively. If I switch up the order and do 14 -> 5 so that it crosses over correctly, it won't go under correctly. Is there a way around that? Thanks again!

Comment: @user112597 That will require some hack I am afraid. You have to insert a phantom row in between and draw two arrows, one below and one above.

Comment: OK, thank you! I had played around with it but had exhausted the possibilities I knew of.